# Magento 2 How to call template file in block file

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, phtml

My block file form.php and I want to call phtml file in this block to display table in this custom admin form, I have no created a layout for this phtml file, if is there any other way to display the table then also suggest me, Thanks

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blog\Edit;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Status;

class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    protected $_systemStore;
    protected $template;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        Status $options,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->options = $options;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => [
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                'method' => 'post'
            ]
            ]
        );
        $file1Url = $model->getFile1();
        $file2Url = $model->getFile2();
        $file3Url = $model->getFile3();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('mtgrid_');
        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Edit Row Data'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);
        } else {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Add Row Data'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'prapproveno',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'prapproveno',
                'label' => __('Prior Approve No.'),
                'id' => 'prapproveno',
                'title' => __('Prior Approve No.'),
                'class' => '',
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'submitdate',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'submitdate',
                'label' => __('Submit Date'),
                'date_format' => $dateFormat,
                'time_format' => 'HH:mm:ss',
                'class' => 'validate-date validate-date-range date-range-custom_theme-from',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'chnlmanager',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'chnlmanager',
                'label' => __('Channel Maneger'),
                'id' => 'chnlmanager',
                'title' => __('Channel Manager'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'status',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'status',
                'label' => __('Status'),
                'id' => 'status',
                'title' => __('Status'),
                'values' => [1=>"Enable",0=>"Disable"],
                'class' => 'status',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'company',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'company',
                'label' => __('Company'),
                'id' => 'company',
                'title' => __('Company'),
                'values' => $this->options->getOptionArray(),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'branch',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'branch',
                'label' => __('Branch'),
                'id' => 'branch',
                'title' => __('Branch'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'avpno',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'avpno',
                'label' => __('AVP/Reseller No.'),
                'id' => 'avpno',
                'title' => __('AVP/Reseller No.'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'budgetfrom',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'budgetfrom',
                'label' => __('Budget From'),
                'id' => 'budgetfrom',
                'title' => __('Budget From'),
                'values' => $this->options->getOptionArray(),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'marketingactivity',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'marketingactivity',
                'label' => __('Marketing Activity'),
                'id' => 'budgetfrom',
                'title' => __('Budget From'),
                'values' => $this->options->getOptionArray(),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'description',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'description',
                'label' => __('Description'),
                'id' => 'description',
                'title' => __('Description'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'file1',
            'file',
            [
                'name' => 'file1',
                'label' => __('Attachments'),
                'id' => 'file1',
                'title' => __('Attachments'),
                'class' => '',
                'note' => 'PDF format only',
                'value'=>$file1Url
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'file2',
            'file',
            [
                'name' => 'file2',
                'label' => __(''),
                'id' => 'file2',
                'title' => __(''),
                'class' => '',
                'note' => 'PDF format only',
                'value'=>$file2Url
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'file3',
            'file',
            [
                'name' => 'file3',
                'label' => __(''),
                'id' => 'file3',
                'title' => __(''),
                'class' => '',
                'note' => 'PDF format only',
                'value'=>$file3Url
            ]
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want show phtml file into form?

Comment: yes@DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your form.php file, Check the below code.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blog\Edit;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Status;

class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
     */
    protected $_rendererFieldset;

    protected $_systemStore;
    protected $template;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        Status $options,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->options = $options;
        $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => [
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                'method' => 'post'
            ]
            ]
        );
        $file1Url = $model->getFile1();
        $file2Url = $model->getFile2();
        $file3Url = $model->getFile3();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('mtgrid_');
        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Edit Row Data'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);
        } else {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Add Row Data'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'prapproveno',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'prapproveno',
                'label' => __('Prior Approve No.'),
                'id' => 'prapproveno',
                'title' => __('Prior Approve No.'),
                'class' => '',
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'submitdate',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'submitdate',
                'label' => __('Submit Date'),
                'date_format' => $dateFormat,
                'time_format' => 'HH:mm:ss',
                'class' => 'validate-date validate-date-range date-range-custom_theme-from',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'chnlmanager',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'chnlmanager',
                'label' => __('Channel Maneger'),
                'id' => 'chnlmanager',
                'title' => __('Channel Manager'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'status',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'status',
                'label' => __('Status'),
                'id' => 'status',
                'title' => __('Status'),
                'values' => [1=>"Enable",0=>"Disable"],
                'class' => 'status',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'company',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'company',
                'label' => __('Company'),
                'id' => 'company',
                'title' => __('Company'),
                'values' => $this->options->getOptionArray(),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'branch',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'branch',
                'label' => __('Branch'),
                'id' => 'branch',
                'title' => __('Branch'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'avpno',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'avpno',
                'label' => __('AVP/Reseller No.'),
                'id' => 'avpno',
                'title' => __('AVP/Reseller No.'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'budgetfrom',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'budgetfrom',
                'label' => __('Budget From'),
                'id' => 'budgetfrom',
                'title' => __('Budget From'),
                'values' => $this->options->getOptionArray(),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'marketingactivity',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'marketingactivity',
                'label' => __('Marketing Activity'),
                'id' => 'budgetfrom',
                'title' => __('Budget From'),
                'values' => $this->options->getOptionArray(),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'description',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'description',
                'label' => __('Description'),
                'id' => 'description',
                'title' => __('Description'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'file1',
            'file',
            [
                'name' => 'file1',
                'label' => __('Attachments'),
                'id' => 'file1',
                'title' => __('Attachments'),
                'class' => '',
                'note' => 'PDF format only',
                'value'=>$file1Url
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'file2',
            'file',
            [
                'name' => 'file2',
                'label' => __(''),
                'id' => 'file2',
                'title' => __(''),
                'class' => '',
                'note' => 'PDF format only',
                'value'=>$file2Url
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'file3',
            'file',
            [
                'name' => 'file3',
                'label' => __(''),
                'id' => 'file3',
                'title' => __(''),
                'class' => '',
                'note' => 'PDF format only',
                'value'=>$file3Url
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'html', 
            'text', 
            [
                'name' => 'html',
                'label' => __('Html Content'),
                'title' => __('Html Content')              
            ]
        )->setRenderer($this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::testtable.phtml'));

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

I have added additional field at the end of the form, Like

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'html', 
            'text', 
            [
                'name' => 'html',
                'label' => __('Html Content'),
                'title' => __('Html Content')              
            ]
        )->setRenderer($this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::testtable.phtml'));
```

Also added

> \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset

In your __construct function, I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank You So much! @KishorThummar it works successfully

Comment: Your welcome, Please upvote the answer also, So it will help others.

Comment: Can i add block file with templete file if so then please tell me how to do that thanks

Comment: Why you need to use block file with the template, You can add functions in form.php and use it in your template file.

Comment: Or you can use any Block file function in your template using below code, Like  
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Company\Helloworld\Block\Main');
echo $blockObj->getMyCustomMethod();
?>